# remove specific filename .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have site:

`mysite.com/welcome`

I wan't to remove the `welcome`-part of the url, but only IF the part is == `welcome`

for example:

`mysite.com/welcome` => `mysite.com/`

`mysite.com/contact` => `mysite.com/contact`

In any other case, the name after mysite.com stays the same.

I know it has something to do with the `.htaccess`-file on my server, but I can't figure out
how exactly I have to realize it. I assume I have to use regular expressions?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule to remove `welcome` only:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/welcome$ /
```

Place this rule in your root .htaccess.

Comment: Hmm... i added this line, but in my url it's still mysite.com/welcome

Comment: Make sure this is first rule in your root .htaccess and your .htaccess is enabled.

Comment: I uploaded my htaccess-file: http://pastebin.com/bvA1gcsy
Tried it at the first line and at the last line ... maybe it has something to do with the REQUEST_FILENAME - part? (lines 129 - 131)

Yes, it says /start$ / - My first site is "start" and not welcome

Comment: If you're already using `mod_rewrite` then use this rule: `RewriteRule ^welcome$ / [L,R=301]` **just below `RewriteBase` line**.

Comment: So right now, i have my htaccess like this:

http://pastebin.com/yw8GXwbM

But still no effect :/

Comment: ok first verify whether your `.htaccess` is enabled or not, by putting same garbage (random) text on top of your `.htaccess` and see if it generates 500 (internal server) error or not?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61352/discussion-between-anubhava-and-dassaffe).